# Magento rewrite /lib/ file?

Tags: php, magento

The only way I've found through search to override a /lib/ file,  specifically /lib/Varien/File/Uploader/,  is to move the file to /local/Varien/File/ and edit it there.

This is fine and all, but I'd like to have the modified file in my modules namespace.  Similar problems, like how to do this with core files, involve rewriting them in your config.xml.   Is it possible to rewrite a /lib/ file in config.xml?

Comment: Why not create your own functionality and `extend Varien_File_Uploader`?

Comment: Would I just redeclare the function in my own file?  Would that override the function declared in the lib file?

Comment: Copy, don't move. Effect is the same though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If you look at how the classes in lib/Varien are instantiated you will see that no factory method is used but the classes are referenced directly by name.